# Lightbox with more jQuery functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jQuery and I've never really played with lightboxes before.

But I've been asked if I can do something for April fools at work, I stupidly said yes as I thought it would be easier than it actually was and now I'm struggling.

I'll give you the idea of what's been asked for.

```
1 - Homepage Banner > Click
2 - On Click a lightbox pops up "Speak your search term"
3 - Click Button To Speak - 5 seconds later "Sorry, we can't hear you, Shout"
4 - Click Button To Shout - "April Fools - Here's a promo code for 10% off. XXXXXX"
```

I have done the last 3 steps - Not sure if they could be done better, but I've fiddled them here: http://jsfiddle.net/C8f3P/1/

I guess what I'm actually asking is, how can I add all of this into a lightbox after a banner has been clicked?  And is a lightbox actually the way to go?

**Note** I've just mocked up something in JSFiddle, it won't look like that :)

Comment: Why the `setTimeout`?

Comment: So the idea is Click - User starts speaking - 5 seconds later it changes asking them to shout.  So the delay is there to simulate something actually picking up speech, where it's actually doing nothing.  Can that be done a different way?  I'm new to jQuery so I only know little bits.  Thanks for your comment

Comment: I think everything is do-able from a functional standpoint in JS. For example Countdown to submit() should be a walk in the park. I think the lightbox tool is your bottleneck.  There are other lightboxes. We use flexslider http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ (maybe) this might be easier to work with?  Also check out the second example which says "this image is wrapped in a link" There is your slide one, click to next slide, and show the next slide which is fake talk search with  countdown of five seconds, slide to next image, "April, fools here is your 10% off code". Just another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I like it!

We have a set up that records search by voice. When the person stops. It submits.

This solution only works with chrome though...

```
<input type="search" name="q" value="" id="searchInputField" placeholder="WHAT CAN WE FIND FOR YOU?" x-webkit-speech="">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchInputField').bind('webkitspeechchange',function() {
        $(this).parent('form').submit(function( event ) {
                  alert( "Speak up I can't hear you!" );
             event.preventDefault();
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

I altered this to have your alert.  Maybe it will help.

If you are using chrome then this will work.  Make sure you have your phone recording the initial response...It should be priceless.

Maybe hide the input in a div somewhere or CSS it off the screen.  Just some ideas.

But this sounds like it would be very funny.  I might do some trickery with my development team.  Thanks for encouraging this deviant behavior :)

Good Luck!

Comment: Just had a try, that's quite cool :)  I appreciate your response but unfortunately we've got to cater for all browsers so it's got to be more simple.  I'd have loved to use something like this though!!

Comment: Ha! :) Well I bet someone will come up with something good for you.  I'm going to keep my eye on this thread. Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my rendition / refactor that can probably help you. However the question you asked is confusing at best and I do not know how to answer it specifically. Hope this code helps.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sukima/PWpaq/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var state = 0;
    var div = $('#fool');
    var content = $('#fool .content');
    var button = $('#fool .button');
    var waiting_html = $('#waiting-content').html();

    function nextStep() {
        var html;

        state++;

        html = $('#step' + state + '-content').html();
        content.html(html);

        div.removeClass('step1 step2 step3').addClass('step' + state);

        if (state >= 3) {
            button.off('click').hide();
        } else {
            button.show();
        }
    }

    $("#fool .button").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        content.html(waiting_html);
        button.hide();
        setTimeout(nextStep, 5000); // Pretend we are recording.
        return false;
    });

    nextStep();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="fool">
    <p class="content"></p>
    <a href="#" class="button"><strong>click</strong> to start recording</a>
</div>

<script id="waiting-content" type="text/html">Recording...</script>
<script id="step1-content" type="text/html">Speak your search term</script>
<script id="step2-content" type="text/html">Sorry, we can't hear you, Shout</script>
<script id="step3-content" type="text/html">April Fools - Here's a promo code for 10% off. XXXXXX</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - What I really need is for all of this to be hidden - Then for it to pop out in a lightbox?  If that makes sense?

Comment: Just updated code to be more in spirit of the OP's april fools joke. http://jsfiddle.net/sukima/PWpaq/1/

Comment: @Nick are you asking how the lightbox API works or are you using the word "lightbox" to convay a concept?

Comment: So I guess I'm not 100% sure what I need.  But I'd like to use something like this - http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/.  If that makes any better sense?

Comment: @Nick, normally the answer for such a question would be an exercise for the student. But I was board so your in luck: http://jsfiddle.net/sukima/PWpaq/2/

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you :)  I'll have a play with this :)